Using CRIU to dump information about files and get images
CRIU introduces several images to keep info about what files are opened by task, but what options should I use to get images such as reg-files.img?
What I have done is as follows：
execl(criu, criu, 
            "dump",
            "--images-dir", dump_dir, 
            "-d", 
            "-vvvv", 
            "-o", dump_log, 
            "-t", pid,
            "--prev-images-dir", prev_dump_dir,
            "--track-mem",
            "--leave-running",
            "--shell-job",
            "--file-locks",
            "--reg-files"

